# Global variable with jquery

Tags: jquery, global-variables

I have a js file test.js that contains a global variable `global_var` and a function `fn1()` that changes the variable `global_var`:

```
var global_var="initial_value";
function fn1(){
    global_var="Value1";
    alert("global_var="+global_var);
}
```

then I execute the `fn1()` from my page1.html that sends me to page2.html:

```
<li><a href="page2.html" onclick='fn1();'></a></li>//this returns "global_var=Value1"
```

Then, in page2.html I want to use the variable `global_var`, but the continous of `global_var` is not changed, it's "initial_value"!!

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
<script>
   $('#mypage').live('pageshow', function(event) {
   alert(global_var); //this returns "initial_value"!!! 
});
</script>
```

Comment: JavaScript execution context/state is not shared between pages.

Comment: consider using sessions or localStorage, the state will not be saved on a new page load.

Comment: You need to store k in a cookie or pass it on the url to page2.html and then read it back in from the url on page2.html.

Comment: Javascript variable scope exists until you reload the page or go away. If you need a value to persist on other pages use a server side language and append your variables to the URL like `page2.php?k=Value1`

Comment: where is your scripts are sitting? in page1 or page2 or separate js?

Comment: @manny: on a separate js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont call the function in page2. Every time you load to an other page your JS will reset... Save it in a SESSION or locally for example if you want to keep it alive!

Answer (score 3):

Every time a new page is loaded javacript is re-initialized and so any change to the variable is lost. You could save tha value in a cookie and retrieve that in page2

page1

```
var global_var="initial_value";
function fn1(){
    global_var="Value1";
    alert("global_var="+global_var);
    $.cookie('global_var', global_var);
}
```

page 2

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
<script>
   $('#mypage').live('pageshow', function(event) {
   var global_var = $.cookie('global_var');
   alert(global_var); //this returns "initial_value"!!! 
});

</script>
```

this requires this plugin https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 2):

"Global" variables in JavaScript on browsers are really page-wide variables. They only exist as long as the `window` object they were created on exists (because all global variables are properties of `window`). When you change pages, the old `window` object is destroyed and a fresh new one is created, so your variable no longer exists.

To persist information between pages, consider:

- Using a cookie.
- Using HTML5 "local storage" (note that IE7 and earlier don't have this, but [IE8 and up do](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage); some mobile browsers may not).
- Using server-side state (but this doesn't scale massively well).

Answer (score 0):

If its matter of two pages only you can use simple querystring

Page1

```
var k="initial_value";
function fn1(){
  k="Value1";
  //  alert("k="+k);
  location.href='page2.html?k='+k;
}
```

Page2

```
function querystring(key) {
   var re=new RegExp('(?:\\?|&)'+key+'=(.*?)(?=&|$)','gi');
   var r=[], m;
   while ((m=re.exec(document.location.search)) != null) r.push(m[1]);
   return r;
}

<script>
   $('#mypage').live('pageshow', function(event) {
   alert(querystring('k'));  
});
```